# Is stemming used when gensim creates a dictionary for tf-idf model?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim

I am using Gensim python toolkit to build tf-idf model for documents. So I need to create a dictionary for all documents first. However, I found Gensim does not use stemming before creating the dictionary and corpus. Am I right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. Gensim doesn't do anything special other than convert what you give it into different models.

Here is the relevant quote and the link that it is from:

> The ways to process documents are so varied and application- and
>   language-dependent that I decided to not constrain them by any
>   interface. Instead, a document is represented by the features
>   extracted from it, not by its “surface” string form: how you get to
>   the features is up to you.

[From Strings to Vectors](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tut1.html#from-strings-to-vectors)

Answer (score 0):

I was also struggling with the same case. To overcome i first stammed documents using `NLTK` and later processed it with `gensim`. Probably it can be a easier and handy way to perform your task.